# Styling the payment methods in the WooCommerce checkout page (Custom Javascript required)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I need some help with a custom Javascript.

I'm trying to style the payment method selections in the WooCommerce checkout page:

[image: Payment method selections in the WooCommerce checkout page]

I would like to be able to separately style the unchecked, checked and hovered states of the payment methods.

I was able to style the regular and hovered states of the payment methods with CSS.

However, there is no way to separately style the checked state of the payment methods as there is no difference between checked & unchecked CSS classes. According to WooCommerce plugin support, this requires a custom Javascript to help identify the checked state.

What should the custom Javascript look like?

Comment: could you show your html..and css you have

Comment: Hi @Frenchy. I don't know how to properly get this info. Here's a [link](https://www.mydreamtattoo.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=3980) to my checkout page so you can check it out for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without your html, you could easily do that with css:

that is an example:

```css
input:checked + label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + *::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.1rem;
  border-color: gray;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + *::before {
  background: radial-gradient(teal 0%, teal 40%, transparent 50%, transparent);
  border-color: teal;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + * {
  color: teal;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Theme color:</legend>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="red" value="#F00">
    <label for="red">Red</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="green" value="#0F0">
    <label for="green">Green</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="blue" value="#00F">
    <label for="blue">Blue</label>
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

For your example you have to set `important` to override woocomerce settings
a sample css for credit cards:

```
#payment_method_stripe:checked + label {
    font-weight: bolder !important;
    font-size: larger !important;
    color: yellow !important;
}
```

[image]

you do same thing with paypal id `payment_method_paypal`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Frenchy, it works perfectly. Is it also possible to target the radio button when it's checked? I'd like to change the color.

Comment: see my answer modified, i change the button.in my snippet.you have to hide before..you could read https://dev.to/kallmanation/styling-a-radio-button-with-only-css-4llc

Comment: or  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp